# How to change Drupal views HTML filter?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-input-format

In default Drupal configuration Views module apply "Filtered HTML" filter to HTML code generated by "Rewrite the output of this field". For some reasons I need "Rewrite the output of this field" to generate the next code:

```
<a href="[token1]" style="background-image:url([token2])">[token3]</a>
```

How can I change "Filter HTML" filter to "Full HTML" filter for the current View?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Drupal 6 with Views 2.

One option is to rewrite the theme template for that specific field in your view. To find out what to name your template file, look at Theme: Information section under "Basic Settings" on the left hand menu of the view edit screen. Depending on the name you use you can be very specific so your template only overwrites this field for this view, or more vague so it can overwrite this type of field for any view you want to do this to.